# Bootstrap Navbar appears as vertical list...?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So I'm following a tutorial online (http://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial-handling-complex-designs/) and following the code exactly, but for some reason, my navbar is not appearing the way it should be. My friend (who's way more experienced with web dev) took a quick look at the code and couldn't figure out what was wrong. So I thought I'd post my problem here.

[image: html code (left), actual page (right)]

I'll also show you my working directory (just in case you're wondering if the files are all in the same directory):

[image]

Here's the code in case you want to try it yourself

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1><a href="#">Bootstrap Site</a></h1>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: which Bootstrap version are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm asuming you are using the latest Bootstrap.

You have to add `navbar-default`to your `<div class="navbar">` and `navbar-nav` to your `<ul class="nav">`.

Which gives you the following markup.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1><a href="#">Bootstrap Site</a></h1>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/115979)

For future problems, try reading the official Bootstrap Docs before asking here. They explained everything very detailed.

[BT Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

I guess your problem is, that the sitepoint tutorial uses an older Bootstrap Version, than the one you downloaded and use.

Comment: I am still getting vertical using the cdn's for bootstrap ):

Comment: @Snickers3192  How did you fix this issue? im facing this current now..

Comment: Man I can't even remember think I just wiped it all out and did something else

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem using bootstrap v4. The previous answers code worked well for me but just wanted to clarify that the part that made the vertical navbar horizontal was to use navbar-expand-lg in the main div tag.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
```

Changing the lg to another size (md, sm or xs) is also helpful depending on your screen sizing preferences.

Hope this helps

Comment: It did - but oddly enough the -lg was not working only for me.  When I used the other variations it did - feels like a bug somewhere in this but thank you.

Answer (score 10):

If you want your navbar to be always horizontal just make it like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
```

Using `navbar-expand-lg|md|sm` will make it always break at some point to vertical position.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying some codes I found on internet based on Bootstrap **version 3** but my app was based on bootstrap **version 4**. There exist important differences between the two versions (see [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/)).

The following code based on v4 works for me :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The official documentation can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/).

Answer (score 2):

**came across your question because I was looking to create a vertical navbar** with bootstrap. I know that **this question is to do the exact opposite**, but since this thread was at the top of the pile on google while searching "bootstrap nav list vertical", I figured I'd leave the solution I found here.

For anyone who can't seem to get bootstrap to behave and render a vertical list, you can use the bootstrap class ".flex-column" in your  tag to turn a horizontal list into a vertical one.

[Here's the page in the Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/), scroll down till you find the subheading 'Vertical':

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

we should use pills or tabs //A grey horizontal navbar that becomes vertical on small screens // for tabs use - nav nav-tabs

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm-bg-light"> 
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
 <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href ="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href ="#">Projects</a></li> 
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: <ul class ="nav nav-pills">

Comment: Don't put code in your comments; edit your answer and add the code there please.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class of the `ul` tag to `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`.

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav">